# Disabling horizontal scrollbar in IntelliJ IDEA nav popups

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I use the navigation pop-up (ie, the "Go To File" modal) in IntelliJ IDEA, there's a horizontal scrollbar that shows up sometimes, which hides the last result, or hides the only result:

[image: Go To File]

Is there any way to hide this scrollbar? In a practical sense, I can of course tell that it's probably found the correct file, and worst case I just go to the wrong file. Just a minor annoyance, really.

Note: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2 under Ubuntu 14.04, using the Unity windows manager. This doesn't happen in the OSX version.

Answer (score 3):

enable soft wrap in

> Editor -> General

reopen IJ

Comment: much better with the touchpad.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me. Eventually what worked was just upgrading IntelliJ to I forget what version, but the latest versions (of IntelliJ and Ubuntu) as of this writing works